# How to fix gmail security error in Chrome by selenium python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, email, selenium, if-statement

I want to open gmail account using selenium python 2.7 in Chrome. I am able to login to gmail account successfully. However, sometimes, I can get **`Its you verify`** massage then it asks for email id or phone number to verify which makes problem of working with that account. So, can we use `if-else` conditions or something else. How can I use `if-else` condition for **it's you verify** step while the login established into gmail account.
Please, suggest me any other way to solve my problem. Thanks 
I am unable to attach screenshoot with this query(stackoverflow.com is not allowing me to attach any images).

Pls, provide if else condition to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch the exception and within your `except` block you would write code that would handle the verification screen process

Answer (score 0):

You can check if "Its you verify" element is present on not , then can proceed with required steps.

```
List <Webelement> verify = driver.findElemnts(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Its you verify')]"));

if(verify.count>0)
{
  //Do verify action
}
```

Above mention xpath is just for example, you can verify before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box...why bother using selenium to drive gmail in the browser?  If you are not testing gmail's browser GUI itself, then I suggest that you use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/gmail/v1) to get your messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that works without any hustle.
Use [Seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) with [undetected browser v2](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection)

> Note: put chromedriver in your sys path.

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time

options = {}
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('your-email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('you-password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
```

In addition to this, selenium wire has many awesome features, check out Github [repository](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)